# Not able to create node pool cluster with promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am trying create a connection to snowflake data base inside the node promise.

```
var NodePoolCluster = require('node-pool-cluster');
var snowflake = require('snowflake-sdk');
init() {

    this.nodePoolCluster = NodePoolCluster.initCluster({
      name: poolName,
      destroy: function (connection) {
        connection.destroy(function (err, connection) {
          if (err) {
            log.error('Unable to disconnect from connection with id: ' + connection.getId() +
              '. Message is: ' + err.message);
          } else {
            log.info('Disconnected connection with id: ' + connection.getId());
          }
        });
      },
      max: maxConnection,
      min: minConnection,
      idleTimeoutMillis: idleTimeoutMillis
    });
    var poolCluster = this.nodePoolCluster;
    return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject) {
      console.log("creating pool");
      poolCluster.addPool(function (callback) {
        console.log("adding pool");
        var connection = snowflake.createConnection({
          account: snowflakeAccountID,
          username: snowflakeUsername,
          password: snowflakePassword,
          database: snowflakeDatabase,
          schema: snowflakeSchema,
          warehouse: snowflakeWarehouse,
          role: snowflakeRole
        });
        console.log("connecting to snowflake");
        connection.connect(function (err, conn) {
          console.log("Inside create connection");
          if (err) {
            log.error('Unable to connect: ' + err.message);
            reject(new Error(err));
            return;
          } else {
            log.info('Successfully connected as id: ' + connection.getId());
            fulfill(callback(err, connection));
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

here is the promise call.

```
var snowFlakePromise = snowflakeObject.init();
      snowFlakePromise.then(function () {
        console.log(connection created);

      }, function (onReject) {
        console.log("connection rejected" + onReject.message);
      });
```

Here I don't get anything after "creating pool", it is not able to add pool to the cluster.
It's works fine without promise but with the promise it is creating problem.

without promise the init() function is like

```
init() {
    this.nodePoolCluster = NodePoolCluster.initCluster({
      name: poolName,
      destroy: function (connection) {
        connection.destroy(function (err, connection) {
          if (err) {
            log.error('Unable to disconnect from connection with id: ' + connection.getId() +
              '. Message is: ' + err.message);
          } else {
            log.info('Disconnected connection with id: ' + connection.getId());
          }
        });
      },
      max: maxConnection,
      min: minConnection,
      idleTimeoutMillis: idleTimeoutMillis
    });

    this.nodePoolCluster.addPool(function (callback) {

      var connection = snowflake.createConnection({
        account: snowflakeAccountID,
        username: snowflakeUsername,
        password: snowflakePassword,
        database: snowflakeDatabase,
        schema: snowflakeSchema,
        warehouse: snowflakeWarehouse,
        role: snowflakeRole
      });

      connection.connect(function (err, conn) {
        if (err) {
          log.error('Unable to connect: ' + err.message);
        } else {
          log.info('Successfully connected as id: ' + connection.getId());
          callback(err, connection);
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: "*It's works fine without promise*" - can you show us that code for comparison?

Comment: @Bergi added the code

Comment: Hm, I can't see much of a difference there.